# I want to build call center and hide the numbers from my workers

Tags: networking, mobile, voip

I have nearly 25,000 mobile numbers to be called, because this database is valued by me , I want to build a call center have 5-10 workers, they will call the numbers by just name and make promotion of my products , I dont wan't that they can see the numbers that should be called.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Asterisk PBX, that will control outgoing calls.
It has API so you can tell asterisk to dial numbers and the agents (workers) will not need to see them.

What I have done in the past is create a queue, and a script that for each contact will place a call in the queue (with command originate from asterisk) and will display whatever info you want on the call name (the client's name for instance).
When the agent answers the call from queue, he reads the name and will immediately start dialling to the client.

Comment: That is https://www.asterisk.org/  and I agree that it is a great tool & can do this job (+1).